# using a locally edited npm package

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, local-node-modules

I made a small modification in a package and I moved this package from `node_modules` to a `dependencies` folder in my angular project directory. Then I edited `package.json` and replaced the version of the specified package by `"file:dependencies/editedpackage"`.

Next, I ran `npm install` in my project directory, a shortcut to `"editedpackage"` was created in `node_modules`.

My problem is when I am importing a module from the package in my solution I receive the following compile error:

> ```
> ERROR in Symbol declared in node_modules/editedpackage/lib/editedpackage is not exported from node_modules/editedpackage .
> ```

Am I missing something? or is there any better way to do that. It's only a small change that I need to have in the package.